# Setting JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu.. not working

Tags: java, ubuntu, sdk

I've downloaded the Java JDK from Oracle.  Just set up Ubuntu on my machine and I'm trying to set JAVA_HOME in my .profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_13
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

ran the command, `. ~/.profile`

then did an echo, and all I'm getting back is JAVA_HOME.
manually did an `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_13`, still nothing once I echo.  What's the deal?

Another stupid question.. when I run

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

even though JRE and JVM are listed, no SDK is listed.. does that mean it isn't installed?  Sorry.. very much a noob.

Comment: Check the output of printenv in terminal and see whether there is JAVA_HOME in the list

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as it fits the exception of "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". It's a simple mistake, but still related to programming in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then did an echo, and all I'm getting back is JAVA_HOME. manually did an export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_13, still nothing once I echo. What's the deal?

The deal is you're typing `echo JAVA_HOME` and it's doing exactly that; printing "JAVA_HOME".

You actually did everything correctly as far as your config; to see the contents of the environment variable, you would do:

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: woooooooow. :| d'oh.  thanks.  turns out i was fine after all...